# Dropzone preview disappears but continues to upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html and I have gotten everything to work, but when I click the start button for the individual upload in the table it will begin the progress and then just disappear, but it will continue to upload behind the scenes.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="container">

  <?php echo form_open_multipart( '/upload/video', $attributes);?>

  <div id="actions" class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
      <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button dz-clickable">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
      </span>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
        <span>Start upload</span>
      </button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
        <span>Cancel upload</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <!-- The global file processing state -->
      <span class="fileupload-process">
          <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></div>
          </div>
        </span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- HTML heavily inspired by http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ -->
      <div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previews">

        <div id="template" class="file-row">
          <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
          <div>
            <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
            <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary start">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
              <span>Start</span>
            </button>
            <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
              <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
            <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
              <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row dropit">
    <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span style="font-size: 72px"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></span>
      <br /><span>Drop videos here to upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple/>;
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get the template HTML and remove it from the doumenthe template HTML and remove it from the doument
  var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
  previewNode.id = "";
  var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
  previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoProcessQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    init: function() {
      myDropzone = this; // closure
      myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        // Hookup the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() {
          myDropzone.processQueue();
        };
      });
      // Update the total progress bar
      myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
      });

      myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
        // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
        // And disable the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      });

      // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
      myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
      });

      // Setup the buttons for all transfers
      // The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
      // `clickable` has already been specified.
      document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function() {
        myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
      };
      document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

If I do exactly whats here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html then nothing works right so I made a few changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Basically what I want to accomplish is the ability to drop multiple files and have the user fill out some date and then click upload for individual files. The only documentation I can find is to upload all files. I want to do one at a time or all.

EDIT: If I remove `autoProcessQueue: false,` it works without any problems. it's only when I'm pushing a button to upload.

EDIT: I have updated my code. I have also narrowed it down to just being an issue with Firefox